# Unable to find Android SDK to build Unity application

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-2.3

I am currently developing an application using Unity3D, and I would like to build the app on the android platform.  When I attempt to build with android, I am always prompted to 'Select Android SDK Root Folder'.  It looks like this:

[image]

My problem is that I cannot find the Android SDK Root Folder, and therefore I cannot build the project.

To attempt to find the correct path, I used the configure SDK manager within Android Studio. I was given this as a path:

/Users/Luke/Library/Android/sdk

[image]

Just be sure, I checked this path in the terminal and found the sdk directory.

[image]

However, when I attempt to use the finder in Unity, I have no idea where the sdk directory is located.  When I follow the path Luke/Library/Android, 
I get a multitude of folders called Android, but none of these folders contain the sdk directory, or even resemble what I'm looking for.

Another pic:

[image]

Obviously, I cannot select any of these directories as the path, and therefore I am stuck at this step in the build.

Question:

1. How might I go about finding the SDK root folder in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simple solution to the problem, thanks to Julien_Nantes on the Unity forums -> https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/os-x-remember-to-install-the-android-sdk-via-the-sdk-manager-not-android-studio.288419/

If the sdk directory is added to the favorites on the left size bar, we can easily select it in the Unity finder.

In order to find the sdk folder in the finder application, I navigated to the correct directory in the command line and ran `open .` With that open, I added the sdk folder as a favorite.